# Error when logging into Bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud

I am trying to log into the Bluemix console, and I see  the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot set property 'next_url' of undefined    at
>   /home/vcap/app/src/orgMgr.js:724:39    at
>   /home/vcap/app/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:756:21    at
>   /home/vcap/app/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:173:37    at
>   /home/vcap/app/src/orgMgr.js:717:17    at EndPoint.sendOpt
>   (/home/vcap/app/src/EndPoint.js:210:8)    at EndPoint.sendReq
>   (/home/vcap/app/src/EndPoint.js:204:17)    at EndPoint.sendGet
>   (/home/vcap/app/src/EndPoint.js:172:17)    at
>   async.doWhilst.responseBody.next_url
>   (/home/vcap/app/src/orgMgr.js:697:24)    at Object.async.whilst
>   (/home/vcap/app/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:763:13)    at
>   Object.async.doWhilst
>   (/home/vcap/app/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:771:22)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment there are login issues in Bluemix public regions.
As reported on Bluemix Status Page

https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/support/#status

> Users are experiencing issues logging into Bluemix in the US-South, EU-GB and AU-SYD regions. The team is aware and investigating a resolution.

updated on 2015-11-16 6:05 UTC: Login to the EU-GB and AU-SYD regions through the cf command-line is working. Only the UI login is experiencing issues in these regions.

Update 2015-11-16 17:45 UTC: The issues with logging into the public Bluemix regions is now resolved and operating as expected

Answer (score 0):

Bluemix platform have Login issues in public regions now.
https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/support/#status

Please check this information and re-try after this issue is resolved.